# Scala Using regular expressions to extract values from a file as a one liner

Tags: regex, scala

I have a one liner (albeit rather long) to extract a value from a configuration file. I am not happy having to apply the regular expression twice (once to match the line and then again to get the group). Does anyone have any suggestions how this could be avoided.

Example data **temp.txt**:

```
scalaVersion=2.11.5
scalaXMLVersion=1.0.3
jUnitVersion=4.8.2
log4JVersion=1.2.17
```

**"One" Liner**

```
val cfg: File = new File("temp.txt")
val regexp = """jUnitVersion=(.*)"""
val version = Source.fromFile(cfg)
                    .getLines
                    .find(_.matches(regexp))
                    .map(regexp.r.findFirstMatchIn(_).get.group(1))
                    .getOrElse("NOTFOUND")
println(version)
```

**Output**

```
4.8.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate version, using the regex as an extractor:

```
val cfg: java.io.File = new java.io.File("temp.txt")
val regexp = """jUnitVersion=(.*)""".r
val version = scala.io.Source.fromFile(cfg)
  .getLines()
  .collectFirst { case regexp(value) => value }
  .getOrElse("NOTFOUND")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val lines = Seq("scalaVersion=2.11.5",
  "scalaXMLVersion=1.0.3",
  "jUnitVersion=4.8.2",
  "log4JVersion=1.2.17")
val regexp = new scala.util.matching.Regex("""jUnitVersion=(.*)""")
val version = lines.
  flatMap(regexp.findFirstMatchIn(_)).
  headOption.
  fold("NOTFOUND")( _.group(1))
```

You can substitute back in Source.fromFile(cfg).getLines for lines.

This reads the file collecting all the regex patterns that match. Takes the first such match and extracts the version number component, hoever if no lines matched, then the "NOTFOUND" branch of the fold is taken.

You avoid the double application by retaining the match instead of filtering, and then applying the extract (group(1)) to the first retained match.

Answer (score 1):

The file you're parsing looks like a standard properties file, so an alternative to messing with regular expressions would be to use Java's built-in `java.util.Properties` to parse it:

```
val cfg: InputStreamReader = Source.fromFile("temp.txt").reader()
val properties: Properties = { val p = new Properties(); p.load(cfg); p }
val version = properties.getProperty("jUnitVersion", "NOTFOUND")
```

Comment: +1. I wouldn't be happy to apply the regex even once - while regular expressions definitely have their place, this is not one of those situations.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I took the properties style file purely to keep the example as simple as possible. I spend alot of time hacking around in diverse data files (previously using perl) and am interested in how I can use Regular expressions in Scala as succinctly as possible.

Comment: @BarneyW I see. I guess sometimes a "minimal, reproducible example" can get a bit too minimal ;) I'll leave this one here for future readers that might indeed have this simpler use case.